# Search bar custom height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, searchbar

I am trying to achieve custom height in search bar. I have tried following code:

```
class SearchBoxWidget extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget  {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(AppSize.s80),
      child: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: new IconButton(
          iconSize: AppSize.large,
          icon: new Icon(
            Icons.search,
          ),
          color: Colors.black,
          tooltip: 'Search',
          onPressed: () {
            print('Pressed Menu');
          },
        ),
        title: TextField(
          autofocus: false,
          cursorColor: AppTheme.colors.themeGreen,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: Constants.searchPlaceHolder,
            hintStyle: AppTheme.textStyle.searchPlaceholder,
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none//BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            enabledBorder:UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none//new BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => new Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

But it is resulting me same height as default as attached screenshot. 
[image]

But I want to achieve following design:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisites**

Take note, this is an open issue in the Flutter SDK. The height of the `AppBar` **cannot** be set to more than `56dp`.

Github Issues:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23373
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7330

**Suggestion**

Play around with the `flexibleSpace` property of the `AppBar`, where you can draw custom `Widget` that will satisfy or close to your requirements, but still...

`flexibleSpace`

> This widget is stacked behind the toolbar and the tab bar. It's height will
>   be the same as the app bar's overall height.

**Furthermore**

Subscribe to the issues posted on Github regarding `AppBar`'s height restriction.

Comment: Hi Code Hunter, do the answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

use the preferred size to set the size you want.

```
 class AppBarCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _AppBarCustomWidgetState();
      }

      @override
      Size get preferredSize => Size(40.0, 60.0);
    }

    class _AppBarCustomWidgetState extends State<AppBarCustomWidget> {
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar( title: Text('hello'),
          );
    }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Salma, this is already what the OP did, it's just that it's impossible (given the restriction), to update the `AppBar` height more than `56dp`.